# Virtual objects on BigQuery

Tags: view, field, google-bigquery, calculated-columns

Is there a way to define virtual objects in BigQuery?

As I have some "complicated" extractions (using regex functions). I would like to have some of them predefined, so every time someone approaches such extraction, they use same predefined logic. I would prefer to avoid pre calculating them and holding them in a new table, as it has its overhead maintenance costs.

I am looking for a way to define virtual tables or virtual fields. the concept is similar to views, or calculated fields, in RDBMS systems such as MS SQL Server.

Is there a way to define such virtual objects that will be calculated only on run time?

Comment: There's not such feature today, but sounds like an interesting feature to request!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you are still looking for an answer: but FWIW, Google BigQuery supports views now.

More information here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#views